# Unable to get the reversed string in python

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python to reverse a string using function reversed but not getting the output .

```
myStr="hello"
rev=reversed(myStr)
print(rev)
```

I am getting the Output - reversed object at 0x000001823DF7DD68

Comment: Use `myStr[::-1]`

Comment: @hiro another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632804/why-strreversed-doesnt-give-me-the-reversed-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) gives you a iterator object and when you print it, you see the string representation of the object `reversed object at 0x000001823DF7DD68`,

Instead, you can use list slicing to reverse the string

```
myStr="hello"
print(myStr[::-1])
```

Or if you want to use the iterator, join it back to a string

```
myStr="hello"

rev=reversed(myStr)

#Join list back to string by passing it the reverse iterator
print(''.join(rev))
```

The output in both cases will be

```
olleh
```

Comment: The `rev=list(reversed(myStr))` line is unecessary. The result of reversed is iterable. So `print(''.join(reversed(myStr)))` is fine

Comment: You are right, I forgot that `join` can take an iterator input, Fixed @oekopez Please check :)